# Why does my redux container render when unrelated state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

My redux state looks like this:

```
{ 
  entities: {
    cars: {
      byId: {},
      isFetching: true
    },
    persons: {
      byId: {},
      isFetching: false
    }  
  }
}
```

My Person container:

```
class PersonPageComponent extends React.PureComponent<
  IPersonPageProps & InjectedAuthRouterProps,
  {}
> {
  render() {
    console.log('render´);
    return (<p>helllo</p>);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState, ownProps: { title: string }) => ({
  list: _.values(state.entities.persons.byId), // personsSelector(state)  
});

export const PersonPage = userIsAuthenticated(
  connect<IPersonPageProps, {}, {}>(
    mapStateToProps
  )(PersonPageComponent)
);
```

Why does my Person container re-render when I have changes in redux state under entities.cars? Is it supposed to trigger render since 'entities' changed? A GET_CARS action sets entities.cars.isFetching = true. Should this result in a re-render in PersonComponent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`state.entities.persons` may be the same object after updating `cars`, but `_.values(state.entities.persons.byId)` produces a new object with each execution – `_.values` does not cache/reuse its result, even if the input stays the same.

Since the prop provided to the `PureComponent` is now a different object (even with identical content), a re-render is triggered.

Comment: If you want to avoid re-render, you can leverage memoization offered for example by reselect: https://github.com/reactjs/reselect

Comment: Thank you! I added reselect, created a selector, and now it only renders when I want it to :) Here is some code for completeness:

    `export const personListSelector = createSelector<RootState,
      { [byId: string]: Readonly<IPerson> },
      ReadonlyArray<IPerson>
    >(state => state.entities.persons.byId, result => _.values(result));`